# Resource Usage for Jenkins Master to Dispatch 200 Jobs?

Tags: jenkins

Is Jenkins capable of managing a large amount of jobs? More specifically, how powerful the Jenkins Master server have to be if it will be connected to, for example, 100 agents with each of them having 2 executors?

Although Jenkins Master is not actually running the real jobs but it still has to monitor the status of the agents and display console outputs, but I have no idea how resource-demanding these tasks are that's why I'm looking for some feedback.

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

To make a right decision about resources and architecture you can read official documentation:

- [calculating](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/architecting-for-scale/#calculating-how-many-jobs-masters-and-executors-are-needed)
- [hardware recommendations](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/hardware-recommendations/#hardware-recommendations)

Or you can read whole article regarding your task
[architecting for scale](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/architecting-for-scale/)

Short atricle:

The equation for estimating the number of masters and executors needed
when the number of configured jobs is known is as follows:

```
masters = number of jobs/500 
executors = number of jobs * 0.03
```

The equation for estimating the maximum number of jobs, masters, and
executors needed for an organization based on the number of developers
is as follows:

```
number of jobs = number of developers * 3.333 
number of masters = number of jobs/500 
number of executors = number of jobs * 0.03
```